# Catch RateLimitError in calls to OpenAI API with python and tenacity's @retry

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, openai-api

I am using python to query the OpenAI API.

I have queries in a list of dictionaries that contain the parameters for each query (a 'system_message' with the instruction and a 'user_message' with the query-specific input.

I define a function `complete_prompt_with_backoff` using `tenacity`'s `@retry` decorator, and two wrapper functions (for other reasons; this is not the required setup but the top-level function needs to take in the entire list of dictionaries).

I then run the following code

```
from openai import AsyncOpenAI
from tenacity import retry, wait_random_exponential, stop_after_attempt
import asyncio

client_async = AsyncOpenAI(api_key="<api_key>", organization="<org_id>")

queries_list_of_dicts = 100 * [{'system_message': 'A description of the role. You are an assistant classifying input. [...]. Return the response as a JSON containing the numerical classification ("class") and the justification ("justification"). For example: {"class": 1, "justification": "this is a positive statement because"}', 'user_message': "Your input to classify is: 'The day was miserable and cold'"}, 
                               {'system_message': 'A description of the role. You are an assistant classifying input. [...]. Return the response as a JSON containing the numerical classification ("class") and the justification ("justification"). For example: {"class": 1, "justification": "this is a positive statement because"}', 'user_message': "Your input to classify is: 'The day was sunny and warm.'"}]

@retry(wait=wait_random_exponential(min=1, max=60), stop=stop_after_attempt(6))
async def complete_prompt_with_backoff(client, system_message: str, user_message: str, **kwargs) -> dict:
    return await client.chat.completions.create(
        messages=[{"role": "system", "content": system_message}, {"role": "user", "content": user_message, }],
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo", )

async def run_compl_backoff_var_prompt_and_get_result_pass_through_args(**kwargs):
    return await complete_prompt_with_backoff(**kwargs)

async def wrapper(queries_ls_dicts, **kwargs):
    return await asyncio.gather(*[run_compl_backoff_var_prompt_and_get_result_pass_through_args(client=client_async, **q) for q in queries_ls_dicts])

results = asyncio.run(wrapper(queries_list_of_dicts))

for res in results:
    print(f"\t{res}")    

print("done")
```

This works until I increase the number of queries and run into the rate limit, throwing the below error. (The code above is in `this_file.py`; paths shortened.)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tenacity/_asyncio.py", line 50, in __call__
    result = await fn(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[...]/this_file.py", line 21, in complete_prompt_with_backoff
    return await client.chat.completions.create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[...]/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/resources/chat/completions.py", line 1199, in create
    return await self._post(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[...]/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 1482, in post
    return await self.request(cast_to, opts, stream=stream, stream_cls=stream_cls)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[...]/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 1283, in request
    return await self._request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[...]/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 1314, in _request
    return await self._retry_request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[...]/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 1364, in _retry_request
    return await self._request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[...]/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 1314, in _request
    return await self._retry_request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[...]/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 1364, in _retry_request
    return await self._request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[...]/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 1326, in _request
    raise self._make_status_error_from_response(err.response) from None
openai.RateLimitError: Error code: 429 - {'error': {'message': 'Rate limit reached for gpt-3.5-turbo in organization org-jiWnW3BOAw31ibSIFFQ9riSc on requests per day (RPD): Limit 10000, Used 10000, Requested 1. Please try again in 8.64s. Visit https://platform.openai.com/account/rate-limits to learn more.', 'type': 'requests', 'param': None, 'code': 'rate_limit_exceeded'}}

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/python@3.11/3.11.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/runpy.py", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[...]/python@3.11/3.11.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/runpy.py", line 88, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "[...]/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.20.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "[...]/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.20.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "[...]/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.20.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "[...]/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.20.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[...]/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.20.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "[...]/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.20.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "[...]/this_file.py", line 31, in <module>
    results = asyncio.run(wrapper(queries_list_of_dicts))
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[...]/python@3.11/3.11.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[...]/python@3.11/3.11.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[...]/python@3.11/3.11.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "this_file.py", line 29, in wrapper
    return await asyncio.gather(*[run_compl_backoff_var_prompt_and_get_result_pass_through_args(client=client_async, **q) for q in queries_ls_dicts])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "this_file.py", line 26, in run_compl_backoff_var_prompt_and_get_result_pass_through_args
    return await complete_prompt_with_backoff(**kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[...]/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tenacity/_asyncio.py", line 88, in async_wrapped
    return await fn(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[...]/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tenacity/_asyncio.py", line 47, in __call__
    do = self.iter(retry_state=retry_state)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[...]/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 326, in iter
    raise retry_exc from fut.exception()
tenacity.RetryError: RetryError[<Future at 0x105b38190 state=finished raised RateLimitError>]
```

Can someone point out to me how to better manage the rate limit? Maybe I'm also not using the `@retry` decorator appropriately or have an issue with `asyncio` that I'm not aware of.

Using the retry function is not a necessity but I need to be able to make one call for a large number of prompts (2-3k) with rather long `'system_message'` and `'user_message'` components that then runs through in one go.

Many thanks for any and all pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a library that can be used for complex RateLimit management like the OpenAI API.

Please install tiktoken to count the number of tokens and multi-rate-limit using pip etc. If you use it with OpenAI, it will look like the following.

```py
from multi_rate_limit import MultiRateLimit, MinuteRateLimit, DayRateLimit
from random import randint, randrange
from tenacity import retry, wait_random_exponential, stop_after_attempt
from typing import List, Tuple
import asyncio
import tiktoken
import time


def count_tokens(text: str) -> int:
    tokenizer = tiktoken.encoding_for_model("gpt-3.5-turbo")
    tokens = tokenizer.encode(text)
    return len(tokens)

async def dummy_openai(text: str) -> Tuple[str, int]:
    in_tokens = count_tokens(text)
    print(f'Start {text[:10]}...(in_token={in_tokens}) at {time.time()}')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return_len = randint(0, len(text))
    return_str = text[:return_len]
    out_tokens = count_tokens(return_str)
    print(f'End {text[:10]}...(in_token={in_tokens}) -> {return_str[:10]}...(out_token={out_tokens}) at {time.time()}')
    return return_str, in_tokens + out_tokens

async def rate_limited_func(text: str) -> Tuple[Tuple[float, List[int]], str]:
    result, used_tokens = await dummy_openai(text)
    # Resouce usage information overwrite (time and request and tokens)
    return (time.time(), [1, used_tokens]), result

async def run_one(mrl: MultiRateLimit, input_text: str):
    # Predict the number of tokens including the output from the number of input tokens.
    predicted_tokens = int(count_tokens(input_text) * 1.5)
    # Reserve a function with 1 request and predicted tokens.
    ticket = mrl.reserve([1, predicted_tokens], rate_limited_func(input_text))
    return await ticket.future

@retry(wait=wait_random_exponential(min=1, max=60), stop=stop_after_attempt(6))
async def run_with_retry(mrl: MultiRateLimit, input_text: str) -> str:
    return await run_one(mrl, input_text)

async def run_with_backoff_and_rate_limit(mrl: MultiRateLimit, input_text: str) -> str:
    return await run_with_retry(mrl, input_text)

async def wrapper(inputs: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    # Free tire of OpenAI gpt-3.5-turbo
    # https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/rate-limits/usage-tiers?context=tier-free
    # The 1st resource represents the number of requests, 3RPM and 200RPD.
    # The 2nd resource represents the number of tokens, 40000RPM.
    # 
    # If you want to adjust the number of tokens over a long period of time (e.g. daily) over multiple runs,
    # please refer to the following page for ‘How to reuse resource consumption information’.
    # https://github.com/largetownsky/multi-rate-limit
    mrl = await MultiRateLimit.create([[MinuteRateLimit(3), DayRateLimit(200)], [MinuteRateLimit(40000)]])
    result = await asyncio.gather(*[run_with_backoff_and_rate_limit(mrl, q) for q in inputs])
    await mrl.term(True)
    return result


def make_random_text(length: int, chars='abcdefgh .') -> str:
    result = ''
    for _ in range(length):
        result += chars[randrange(0, len(chars))]
    return result


inputs = [make_random_text(randint(500, 40000)) for _ in range(10)]
results = asyncio.run(wrapper(inputs))
for input, res in zip(inputs, results):
    print(f'{input[:10]}... -> {res[:10]}...')
print("done")
```

The result will look something like this:

```
poetry run python expr\openai_sample.py
Start befh bdhfb...(in_token=11998) at 1702317720.1627202
End befh bdhfb...(in_token=11998) -> befh bdhfb...(out_token=10167) at 1702317721.170654
Start gh bgdgge ...(in_token=16326) at 1702317781.2059288
End gh bgdgge ...(in_token=16326) -> gh bgdgge ...(out_token=4107) at 1702317782.2253807
Start hh bd.de.d...(in_token=15052) at 1702317842.2468073
End hh bd.de.d...(in_token=15052) -> hh bd.de.d...(out_token=6884) at 1702317843.2636018
Start ac fdaabfe...(in_token=16917) at 1702317903.2821822
End ac fdaabfe...(in_token=16917) -> ac fdaabfe...(out_token=9606) at 1702317904.2908852
Start bcg.fe. . ...(in_token=3143) at 1702317904.2928865
End bcg.fe. . ...(in_token=3143) -> bcg.fe. . ...(out_token=2434) at 1702317905.302957
Start .bdeffcd.g...(in_token=6301) at 1702317964.3101747
End .bdeffcd.g...(in_token=6301) -> .bdeffcd.g...(out_token=4022) at 1702317965.319343
Start hc.cbh bba...(in_token=1851) at 1702317965.3203163
End hc.cbh bba...(in_token=1851) -> hc.cbh bba...(out_token=677) at 1702317966.333362
Start c efcb hef...(in_token=14163) at 1702317966.3413603
End c efcb hef...(in_token=14163) -> c efcb hef...(out_token=4509) at 1702317967.3498619
Start gg.d hebha...(in_token=15912) at 1702318027.3840196
End gg.d hebha...(in_token=15912) -> gg.d hebha...(out_token=9028) at 1702318028.3987768
Start ghaeb h  b...(in_token=13962) at 1702318088.418738
End ghaeb h  b...(in_token=13962) -> ghaeb h  b...(out_token=5122) at 1702318089.432167
befh bdhfb... -> befh bdhfb...
gh bgdgge ... -> gh bgdgge ...
hh bd.de.d... -> hh bd.de.d...
ac fdaabfe... -> ac fdaabfe...
bcg.fe. . ... -> bcg.fe. . ...
.bdeffcd.g... -> .bdeffcd.g...
hc.cbh bba... -> hc.cbh bba...
c efcb hef... -> c efcb hef...
gg.d hebha... -> gg.d hebha...
ghaeb h  b... -> ghaeb h  b...
done
```

You can see that in areas where there are many tokens, it adheres to 40,000 TPM and calls only 1 to 2 times per minute, and in areas where there are few tokens, it adheres to 3 RPM and makes 3 calls per minute.